# jQuery ui autocomplete - puts <strong> on each character seperatly

Tags: jquery-ui

I don't know if this is the default behavior but the numbers are flipped when this happens:

If I got a autocomplete input, and got a value inside "גדכעד 50"  it displayed as "גדכעד 05"

the 50 displayed as 05 because jquery puts  between each character.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: does it happens without using hebrew?

Comment: I think the in ltr lang it won't happen cause the numbers go same direction as text.

Comment: I'm using jquery-ui combobox. fill it with values from googke maps geocoder service.

Comment: "בנדיקט - שדרות רוטשילד,רוטשילד 29, תל אביב" this is a sample response from google maps api, the 29 shown as 92 inside the autocomplete box, after selecting the object, it displays 29 as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, It's inside the jquery combobox code, it formats the items with  on each char.